# How do I install libglade2-0?

Tags: installation, drivers

I'm trying to install a Canon MF4450 printer from a network to Ubuntu. I have a driver file from Canon's website `Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V270_us_EN.tar.gz`. Two  `*.deb` files are contained in the original file. The Printer installer is asking me for a PPD file format to be chosen in driver file selection. I'm using this command:

```
/folder$ sudo dpkg -i file_name.deb
```

...in the terminal and it has a dependency problem on libglade2-0 - `this package is not installed`. How can I install this package?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the complete output of the `sudo dpkg -i` command?

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if it'll help, this was on Debian Jessie, so YMMV
I was running a ./configure command and getting:
No package 'libglade-2.0' found

So, tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglade2-0
```

and getting:
libglade2-0 is already the newest version.
(./configure still generating same error)

Finally tried:

> $ sudo apt-get install libglade2-dev

and it seemed to fix the problem
(configure worked, then make worked)

Comment: Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can install that package by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libglade2-0
```

Another simple way to install any package is from Synaptic Package Manager. Install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Open Synaptic and search for the packages you want to install.